# Rewrite recursive function to iterative one

Tags: java

> A short flight of stairs will be called a construction of cubes in which each next level consists of a strictly larger number of cubes than the previous level, if we count the levels from top to bottom. You need to count the number of ladders that can be built exactly from n cubes.

My solution to this task doesn't pass the time test. To fix this, I decided to try to rewrite the recursive function to the usual one, but so far it has not worked out very well.

```
public class main {
    int n;

    public static int counts(int prev_level, int n) {
        if (n == 0){
            return 1;
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int level =1; level<prev_level; level++){
            if((n-level)<0)
                break;
            count += counts(level,n-level);
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        int res = 0;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                res = counts(n+1,n);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) { System.out.println("Input error"); }
        try{
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(writer);
            p.println(res);
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) { System.out.println("Output error"); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Rewriting as non-recursive doesn't make it faster. you need a better algorithm.

Comment: ... but it usually does reduce the risk of a stack overflow exception

Comment: what is the use case. What does the algorithm do?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: of course. but i'd expect it to run out of stack space and error out before it could time out. if there was an error would it be displayed?

Comment: Looks like many recalculations are happening over and over again in the counts() function. Here is a related problem that is solved with memoization, should be similar: https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2018/02/09/Solving-the-Fibonacci-problem-using-Dynamic-Programming-in-Java

Comment: I agree with @NathanHughes, you should change the algorithm, Fork-Join could help the count method.